# Modelling Circuit from FSM using Verilog

Tags: verilog, state-machines, modeling

I am trying to understand the concept of modeling a circuit from a FSM in Verilog.

I have tried to write down the procedure that I have used in the image below just to make sure that I did it right:
[image]

Based on the solution the circuit is as below:
[image]

The Verilog code I have developed is:-

```
//----------------------------------------
//module bit stream generator
//-----------------------------------------

module generator(
clk,    
stream  //generated stream
);
output stream;
input clk;
reg c;
wire stream;
assign stream=c;

initial
begin
c=1'd0;
end

always@(posedge clk)
begin
    //c=!c;
    c = {$random} %2;
    //$display("a= %b",c);
end
endmodule



//----------------------------------------
//module D flip flip
//-----------------------------------------

module d(q_w,q0_w,d,c);
output q_w,q0_w;
input c,d;

//wire c;
reg q,q0;
wire q_w,q0_w;
assign q_w=q;
assign q0_w=q0;

    initial 
       begin
           q=1'b0; q0=1'b1;
      end
    always @ (posedge c)
       begin 
         q=d;
         q0= ~d;
       end
endmodule


//----------------------------------------
//module sequencedetector
//-----------------------------------------

module sequencedetector(
clk,
x,  //input bit stream
out //output from sequence detector
);

input x,clk;
output out;

wire x,y0,y_0,y1,y_1,g12,g32,g2d1,out;

d dff1(.q_w(y1),.q0_w(y_1),.d(g2d1),.c(clk));   //flip flop D1
d dff0(.q_w(y0),.q0_w(y_0),.d(x),.c(clk));  //Flip Flop D2

and gate1(g12,x,y0);
or gate2(g2d1,g12,g32);
and gate3(g32,y1,y0);
and gate4(out,x,y_0,y1);

endmodule


//----------------------------------------
//module sequencedetector testbench
//-----------------------------------------

module sequencedetector_tb;

reg clk;
wire out,x;

sequencedetector UUT(
.clk(clk),
.x(x),
.out(out));

generator UUTgen(
.clk(clk),
.stream(x));



initial begin
clk=1'b0;
//stream=1'b0;
//=1'b0;
end

initial  
begin
    $dumpfile ("counter.vcd"); 
    $dumpvars(0); 
end

always
    begin
    #20 clk=!clk;
    end

initial
    begin
    #20000 $finish;
    end 
endmodule
```

But sadly the I the output is not as expected The circuit does not detect any seqience as the output is always LOW.
Am not able to upload the GTKwave snapshot in want of sufficient reputation.

Any help is highly appreciated

### EDIT

Just figured out that in the code for the flip Flop the output(q) was not following the input(d) whenever the input bit changed for one cycle only, probably because the sampling was being done at same instance as shifts were happening(in the bit stream). This code was requiring the changed bits to sustain atleast 2 cycles to be followed by the flip flop output. Introduced a delay of 2 cycles in the flip flop code and the output is as expected.

```
always @ (posedge c)
           begin 
            #2 q=d;
             q0= ~d;
           end
```

The problem now is what should I do if I need to implement the Verilog code on a an actual hardware. I mean what is the alternate of delay (#2) if i need to make a synthesizeble code (definitely not multitude of gates) but some standard hardware friendly verilog function, maybe.

Comment: Am putting up the entire picture as I am not able to verify the circuit through a 'dry-run'. Just followed the steps for conversion of FSM to a circuit from many tutorials.

Comment: At clock posedge you likely want something like q<=d instead of q=d. Look up blocking versus nonblocking assignments in your textbook or the Verilog spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a nonblocking assignment. These assignments change at the clock edge.

```
always @ (posedge c)
begin 
    q  <= d;
    q0 <= ~d;
end
```

In order to illustrate the implications of blocking vs non-blocking assignment, consider the following example.

Two outputs, A and B. A is driven by the input, and B is driven by to A.

```
module flipflop(
    input c,
    input d,
    output reg a,
    output reg b
    );

   always@(posedge c) begin
      a        <= d;
      b        <= a;

   end
endmodule
```

That produces this:

[image: ab non blocking]

As you can see, there is a flip flop between output A and output B.

Now the blocking example:

```
module flipflop(
    input c,
    input d,
    output reg a,
    output reg b
    );

   always@(posedge c) begin
      a        = d;
      b        = a;

   end
endmodule
```

That produces this:

[image: ab blocking]

There is no delay between A and B anymore.

If you want a delay of multiple cc, it's necessary to use a non-blocking assignment in order to infer the correct number of FF needed. Here's an example of a triple registered signal in hw which creates a 3cc delay:

```
module flipflop(
    input c,
    input d,
    output q
    );

   reg [2:0]   q_i;

   always@(posedge c) begin
      q_i[0]   <= d;
      q_i[2:1] <= q_i[1:0];

   end

   assign q = q_i[2];


endmodule
```

It creates this schematic in synthesis:

[image: triple reg blocking]

The tools have inferred FDREs in these cases. See the [xilinx libraries guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx14_1/7series_scm.pdf) (page 185) to give you an idea of what primitives are available (altera will have similar ones, probably).

I ran your code in vivado 2015.3 and it worked fine:

[image]

Comment: Although I understand the difference between blocking and non blocking call( theoretical atleast), it doesnt really seem to have much difference on the working of the FF in my code (simulated  runs). Are you saying that, non blocking assignments  will be mandatory if this code is required to be 'burnt' on an FPGA?... The only way in my code I could get Q following D was by inducing a delay (#1) irrespective of blocking or non blocking modes used. 2) Is there a significance to why the D input wire has been made blue(incomplete too).

Comment: I've edited my answer. Blocking and non blocking are both ok in hw, but using blocking changes the behaviour and will result in fewer FDREs being used. It's possible to use both, but it's important to understand the differences in the resulting schematic produced.

Comment: This was enlightening!! You wrote _"If you want a delay of multiple cc, it's necessary to use a blocking assignment in order to infer the correct number of FF needed."_ , but the following example you gave was with non blocking assignment. Was it supposed to be like that, or is it a typo. Thanks for your time and concern :)

Comment: Oh, that was a typo! A *non-blocking* assignment is needed :)

Comment: @sherinkapotein PS:  I use non-blocking assignments way more than blocking. I find it easier to predict the behaviour and final circuit if I use non-blocking (because every assign becomes a FDRE)

Comment: A doubt still continues to confuse. What is the alternative to **#2** that i was _forced_ to add in the flip flop code (as i mentioned earlier; Q wasn't following D unless this delay was introduced) . I mean, is it an acceptable practice if I use such delay while trying to implement this code on an FPGA?

Comment: I tested your code in vivado 2015.3 without the delay (just q <= d) and it worked. how were you testing?

Comment: Also, the alternative to #2 that I suggested was the triple register example above, but it doesn't seem like it's necessary. sometime it is in HW if you don't know if a signal is synchronous to the clock.

Comment: I used GTKwave to observe waveforms. This link is without delay [link](http://postimg.org/image/8qgjx56nf/). The second link is with delay introduced. [link](http://postimg.org/image/udyvq74eh/). Notice how Q starts accurately following D with the delay.